# During an update of Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS getting some crap?

Tags: 22.04

can someone help me in fixing this issue ? while I updating the newly installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Suggestions appreciated.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

```
 **sudo apt-get update**
Hit:1 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                    
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                         
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                            
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                       
Hit:6 http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease                                              
Hit:7 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                  
Get:8 https://mega.nz/linux/repo/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease [2 993 B]          
Fetched 113 kB in 1s (127 kB/s)                                           
Reading package lists... Done
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-charmander-14/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-charmander-14' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-charmander-14/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-charmander-14' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-charmander-14/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-charmander-14' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-charmander-14/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-charmander-14' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-charmander-14/i18n/Translation-nb' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-charmander-14' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-charmander-14/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-charmander-14' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-charmander-14/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-charmander-14' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-charmander-14/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-charmander-14' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-charmander-14/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-charmander-14' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-charmander-14/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-charmander-14' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

I try to find this in source file, which I'm unable to find it ?
Do I navigated to the correct file or not ? suggestions please.

```
total 64K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K sep.  15 01:04 apt.conf.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K april  9  2020 auth.conf.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K juli  28 09:26 keyrings
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K april  9  2020 preferences.d
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 3,0K sep.  15 00:21 sources.list
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K sep.  15 01:35 sources.list.d
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 3,3K sep.  15 00:21 sources.list.distUpgrade
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 3,3K okt.  23  2021 sources.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14K feb.  22  2022 trusted.gpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12K okt.   5  2021 trusted.gpg~
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4,0K sep.  15 00:52 trusted.gpg.d

**cat /etc/apt/sources.list**


# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200423)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
```

**ls -lh /etc/apt/sources.list.d/***

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  130 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  130 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  190 sep.  15 01:35 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 okt.  23  2021 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  161 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  128 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  128 okt.  23  2021 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linrunner-ubuntu-tlp-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  171 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxuprising-ubuntu-apps-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  138 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxuprising-ubuntu-apps-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  138 okt.  23  2021 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxuprising-ubuntu-apps-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  177 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxuprising-ubuntu-shutter-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  144 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxuprising-ubuntu-shutter-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  144 okt.  23  2021 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxuprising-ubuntu-shutter-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  108 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/megasync.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  108 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/megasync.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  492 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mendeleydesktop.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  459 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mendeleydesktop.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  264 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-somerville-charmander-14-meta.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  264 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-somerville-charmander-14-meta.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  195 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pinta-maintainers-ubuntu-pinta-stable-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  162 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pinta-maintainers-ubuntu-pinta-stable-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  229 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  196 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  196 okt.  23  2021 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,3K sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,2K sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,2K okt.  23  2021 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  236 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  203 sep.  15 00:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  203 okt.  23  2021 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list.save
(base) ➜  ~
```

Comment: The title is wrong. You can update, but you have some crap in your sources.list. We can't guess how it got there.

Comment: I see, how do I remove the configured file ?

Comment: If you post contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` we can help. Did you install some custom Dell image?

Comment: There are additional sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`. Post the contents of those files, too.

Comment: @Pilot6 I already posted the contents of sources.list, please have a look.

Comment: @ – user535733, I updated the post with additional sources.

Comment: I don't know why this thread is down voted  I don't really understand ?

Comment: Never mind. Somebody downvoted. This happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-somerville-charmander-14-meta*
```

This will delete that source.You can previously save these files for reference, but I don't think it will be needed.

Now you should run `sudo apt update` without errors.

Comment: Thanks @ Pilot6.